Any solution to apply rounded corners in Jetpack Glance
Is there any solution to apply rounded corners in Rows or Columns in Jetpack Glance
cornerRadius works only in android S+, so any workaround ?
@Composable
fun ParkingSessionsWidget(sessions: List<ParkingSession>) {
    Column(
        modifier = GlanceModifier.fillMaxWidth()
            .height(100.dp)
            .padding(16.dp)
            .background(Color.White)
            .cornerRadius(100.dp)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Active sessions",
            style = defaultTextStyle.copy(fontSize = 20.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold),
            modifier = GlanceModifier.padding(16.dp)
        )

    }
}


One solutions is to use AndroidRemoteViews,
AndroidRemoteViews(
    remoteViews = RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.my_container_view),
    containerViewId = R.id.example_id
) {
    Column(
        modifier = GlanceModifier.fillMaxWidth()
            .height(100.dp)
            .padding(16.dp)
            .background(Color.White)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Active sessions",
            style = defaultTextStyle.copy(fontSize = 20.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold),
            modifier = GlanceModifier.padding(16.dp)
        )

    }
} 

And you can define your container view like this -
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/drawable_res_with_rounded_corners"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/example_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

Source : https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/glance/interoperability

You could use a shape drawable as first child on a box to make that shape look like its background around the text.
For instance,
circular_background.xml
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="100dp" />
</shape>

Then in your glance code:
@Composable
fun ParkingSessionsWidget(sessions: List<ParkingSession>) {
    Box(
        modifier = GlanceModifier.fillMaxWidth()
            .height(100.dp)
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        Image(
            provider = ImageProvider(R.drawable.circular_background),
            contentDescription = null, // decorative 
            colorFilter = GlanceTheme.colors.primary,
            modifier = GlanceModifier.fillMaxSize()
        )
        Text(
            text = "Active sessions",
            style = defaultTextStyle.copy(fontSize = 20.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold),
            modifier = GlanceModifier.padding(16.dp)
        )
    }
}

If your box will need to be clickable, you can also provide a ripple override within the clickable modifier to make the ripple match the shape. From your example, I am assuming it's not clickable.
